# How to design Graphene metasurface using COMSOL?

Tags: graphene, metamaterials

I want to simulate a graphene based metasurface using COMSOL. Can anyone tell me the steps of defining Graphene in COMSOL or provide any tutorial for the same?

Comment: I think COMSOL only works for continuous models, not for atomistic ones.

Comment: It looks like this has been discussed on the COMSOL website, including a tutorial and example input files: https://www.comsol.com/blogs/should-we-model-graphene-as-a-2d-sheet-or-thin-3d-volume/. I'm not a COMSOL user, so I can't access the example files, but maybe someone else will be able to.

Comment: This question seems to be abandoned (OP has not logged in for several months). It can be reopened if OP returns or someone would like to provide an answer.

Comment: @Camps it looks like Tyberius found a website that discusses input files for this problem. Now that you've seen that, do you think you can answer this question?